# Best way to pass custom options to function

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

I am writing a wrapper to a REST API. So, whenever I am retrieving items from the server, I just need to play around with the parameters (in the uri). The way I am doing it now works fine but I just feel there must be another elegance way to do this maybe with `enum` or something.

I don't like that I need to 'know' what are the options are as the `Dictionary` type is `string`. I tried with `Dictionary<EnumType, string>`, but I have more than one type of `enum`. Plus, I am not sure how to map the `EnumType` (key) to the appropriate value.

Basically, I am trying to avoid as much as possible the use of magic keyword.

Here is my partial code:

```
public string GetUnreadItems()
{
    var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    options.Add("ItemType", "Unread");
    options.Add("SortBy", "Latest");
    // GetItemsBasedOn(options);
}

public string GetAllItems()
{
    var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    options.Add("ItemType", "All");
    // GetItemsBasedOn(options);
}

public string GetItemsBasedOn(Dictionary<string, string> options)
{
    // Do request here based on options passed
    // and return the result to caller function 
}
```

EDIT:
This is what I am trying to implement http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve

I would like to implement the options `sort`, `detailType`, `contentType`, `Favorite`, and `State`. And each of the options have their own options but only one can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about improving your current design. I don't agree that the solution I am about to present to you is the ideal solution, but given that you have already identified that you would like to use an `enum` I think you will be content with this solution.

What you can do is define an `enum` marked with the `[Flags]` attribute. Assign to each flag in the enum a value that is a power of two. If you want to combine options to create a single option use [bitwise or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) just like I did with the flag named "All" in the proceeding sample:

```
[Flags]
public enum GetItemOptions
{
    Read = 0x1,
    Unread = 0x2,
    All = 0x1 | 0x2,
    SortByOldest = 0x4,
    SortByLatest = 0x8
}
```

From your code sample, the first call will now look like this:

```
GetItemsBasedOn(GetItemOptions.Unread | GetItemOptions.SortByLatest);
```

And the second will look like this:

```
GetItemsBasedOn(GetItemOptions.All);
```

In order to enable this design you will need to adjust your `GetItemsBasedOn` method signature so that it specifies an argument of the `GetItemOptions` enum type. Below is an example of how you can handle different settings.

```
public static void GetItemsBasedOn(GetItemOptions getItemOption)
{
    if (getItemOption.HasFlag(GetItemOptions.SortByOldest) && getItemOption.HasFlag(GetItemOptions.SortByLatest))
        throw new ArgumentException("I can't sort by both...");

    if (getItemOption.HasFlag(GetItemOptions.Read))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("READ");
    }

    if (getItemOption.HasFlag(GetItemOptions.Unread))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UNREAD");
    }

    if (getItemOption.HasFlag(GetItemOptions.SortByOldest))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SORT BY OLDEST");
    }
    else if (getItemOption.HasFlag(GetItemOptions.SortByLatest))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SORT BY NLATEST");
    }
}
```

I don't think you know much about bit-wise operations, and for that reason I simplified the code sample as much as possible by utilizing the `Enum.HasFlag` method which simply checks if the given `GetItemOptions` enum has a flag specified.

You may have bared witness to this pattern before when using [`RegexOptions Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) or [`ControlStyles Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx)

### Update

I would suggest that you create an `enum` for each parameter and define a class like this:

```
public class PocketDataRequest
{
    public State? State { get; set; }
    public Favourite? Favourite { get; set; }
    public ContentType? ContentType { get; set; }
    public Sort? Sort { get; set; }
    public DetailType? DetailType { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> ToPostData()
    {
        return GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(p => p.GetValue(this, null) != null)
                        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, 
                                      p => p.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
    }
}
```

This would leverage the following syntax:

```
PocketDataRequest pocketDataRequest = new PocketDataRequest();
pocketDataRequest.State = State.Unread;
pocketDataRequest.Sort = Sort.Newest;
GetItemsBasedOn(pocketDataRequest.ToPostData());
```

In my implementations `ToPostData` method, I use LINQ and Reflection, that is just because I am lazy. You need to manually evaluate each `enum` value, especially if you want to change the `enum` names to something more appropriate. Also, my code will fail if you try and pass the parameter titled `favorite`. This is because `favorite` takes either the number "0" or "1". This is not a big problem because what you can do it define the `enum` like this:

```
public enum Favourite
{
    UnfavouritedItems = 0,
    FavouritedItems = 1
}
```

and then simply cast the value `(Int32)` and add that value to the `Dictionary<string, string>` or `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: I know bit-wise and thought of using it, but that would give the option to users to have multiple selection just like the `SortBy` above. I need to do additional checking. What are some other neat patterns for this? If not, I would just implement your suggestion and see how it goes. My focus is on maintainability of this wrapper, that's the reason why I am avoiding as much as possible magic words.

Comment: @ShulhiSapli I did account for that with the `if` statement. Can you update your question with a list of all of the possible options (e.g. SortByRead, SortByUnread, SortByImportant?). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I think this should do it. Thanks a lot!